# Can't post topic to phpbb-forum by code

Tags: php, post, phpbb

I wonder why this code won't submit a new topic to the forums.

```
<?php
    define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    $phpbb_root_path = '../PHPBB3/';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);

    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_posting.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/message_parser.' . $phpEx);
    include '/phpBB3/includes/functions_posting.php';

    function unhtmlentities($string)
   {
      // replace numeric entities
      $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
      $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
      // replace literal entities
      $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
      $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
      return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
   }

    /*   //debug - uncomment for testing
        $_POST["username"] = "username";
        $_POST["password"] = "password";
        $_POST["title"] = "thread title";
        $_POST["text"] = "thread comment";
        $_POST["forumid"] = 24; //this is the forum id you wanna post to (required for a reply too)
        $_POST["topicid"] = ''; //if you wanna submit a reply to a thread add topic id here
    */

    $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);
    $Prioritet = $_POST['priority'];
    $Typ = $_POST['type'];
    $text = utf8_normalize_nfc($text);

    $poll = $uid = $bitfield = $options = '';
    generate_text_for_storage($text, $uid, $bitfield, $bbcode_options, false, false, false);

    $subject = utf8_normalize_nfc($title);
    $username = utf8_normalize_nfc($name);
    $data = array( 
    // General Posting Settings
    'forum_id'            => 2,    // The forum ID in which the post will be placed. (int)
    'topic_id'            => 0,    // Post a new topic or in an existing one? Set to 0 to create a new one, if not, specify your topic ID here instead.
    'icon_id'            => false,    // The Icon ID in which the post will be displayed with on the viewforum, set to false for icon_id. (int)

    // Defining Post Options
    'enable_bbcode'    => true,    // Enable BBcode in this post. (bool)
    'enable_smilies'    => false,    // Enabe smilies in this post. (bool)
    'enable_urls'        => true,    // Enable self-parsing URL links in this post. (bool)
    'enable_sig'        => true,    // Enable the signature of the poster to be displayed in the post. (bool)

    // Message Body
    'message'            => $text,        // Your text you wish to have submitted. It should pass through generate_text_for_storage() before this. (string)
    'message_md5'    => md5($text),// The md5 hash of your message

    // Values from generate_text_for_storage()
    'bbcode_bitfield'    => $bitfield,    // Value created from the generate_text_for_storage() function.
    'bbcode_uid'        => $uid,        // Value created from the generate_text_for_storage() function.

    // Other Options
    'post_edit_locked'    => 1,        // Disallow post editing? 1 = Yes, 0 = No
    'topic_title'        => $subject,    // Subject/Title of the topic. (string)

    // Email Notification Settings
    'notify_set'        => false,        // (bool)
    'notify'            => false,        // (bool)
    'post_time'         => 0,        // Set a specific time, use 0 to let submit_post() take care of getting the proper time (int)
    'forum_name'        => '',        // For identifying the name of the forum in a notification email. (string)

    // Indexing
    'enable_indexing'    => true,        // Allow indexing the post? (bool)

    // 3.0.6
    'force_approved_state'    => true, // Allow the post to be submitted without going into unapproved queue

    // 3.1-dev, overwrites force_approve_state
    'force_visibility'            => true, // Allow the post to be submitted without going into unapproved queue, or make it be deleted
    );

    submit_post('post', $subject, $username, POST_NORMAL, $poll, $data, [$update_message = true]);
?>
```

Right now, it only shows a white page instead of the html code I have above and there is no new post on the forums. Figured it have to be something in the php-code, but can't seem to find the fault. I appreciate all answers I can get!

EDIT: The problem is in the submit_post function. Perhaps bad-linking or missing variable?

EDIT 2: Edited code. Only problem right now is that the text won't be posted on the forums!

EDIT 3: This is the error log: Warning: include(../PHPBB3/common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 15

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../PHPBB3/common.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 15

Warning: include(../PHPBB3/includes/functions_posting.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 16

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../PHPBB3/includes/functions_posting.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 16

Warning: include(../PHPBB3/includes/message_parser.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 17

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../PHPBB3/includes/message_parser.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 17

Warning: include(/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/includes/functions_posting.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 18

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/includes/functions_posting.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 18

Fatal error: Call to undefined function utf8_normalize_nfc() in /www/webvol11/jc/87yqo3f2oz6gicm/baaw.se/public_html/phpBB3/formhandled.php on line 45

Seems to be some problems...

EDIT 4: Fixed the errors, now I got a new one. 
General Error
SQL ERROR [ mysqli ]

Column 'topic_first_poster_colour' cannot be null [1048]

An sql error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact an administrator if this problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $message = = generate_text_for_storage($meddelande, $new_uid, $new_bitfield, $bbcode_options, false, false, false);
```

Should be

```
  $message = generate_text_for_storage($meddelande, $new_uid, $new_bitfield, $bbcode_options, false, false, false);
```

You have an extra = sign in there
I also think this:

```
$mode = post;
```

Should be

```
$mode = 'post';
```

I think $mode expects a string (from memory, been a while since I played with submit_post)
*edit* Yes the 1st parameter is a string. "Can be post, edit, reply, or delete." - taken form the [wiki](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.submit_post)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still got problems however. Still no post and blank page.

Comment: Looking at your edits, you have a duplicate include for functions_posting.php - is that actually in your code, or just an error on here? Are you still getting a blank page form your new code?

Comment: Yep, seems like I included it twice. The page isn't blank anymore. It just won't post to the forums.

Comment: Hm, ok I don't see anything immediately wrong (unfortunately don't have an install handy I can check). Is there anything noted in your error logs? Could be there is an error being suppressed. I'll see if I can get a local copy of phpBB set up later tonight and have a poke around

Comment: Cleared all issues now. I just needed to start the session!

Comment: Ah great, glad to see you got it sorted :)